# Sidekiq logging to both terminal and log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, log4r

I'm using Sidekiq to queue up some jobs in my Rails server. As per the [Logging](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging) wiki, it's as simple as adding the following in *config/sidekiq.yml*

```
---
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency:  25
```

However, now this only logs to that log file, what if I do want to write out to STDOUT as well (atleast in development)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Get rid of the logfile statement.

```
bundle exec sidekiq | tee ./log/sidekiq.log
```